# PHP / MySQL запрос не вернул никаких данных

Tags: php, mysql

есть несколько станции в БД нужно разделить на 3 категории: 1)первая станция 2)последняя станция 3)промежуточные станции.
попробовал вот так но выдает ошибку

```
$line_station_result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `station` 
WHERE `line_id`='{$row['id']}' ORDER BY `position_station`");

$row_line_station_result = mysqli_fetch_row($line_station_result);
$start_station = array_shift($row_line_station_result);
$end_station = array_pop($row_line_station_result);
```

Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\OSPanel\domains\ATC\xml.php on line 190

Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\OSPanel\domains\ATC\xml.php on line 191

Comment: я переписал заголовок вопроса, поскольку он не имел отношения к проблеме.

Comment: у вас же там ясно написано что $row_line_station_result  должен быть массивом

Comment: Смотрите ошибки, которые возвращает mysql